# Accidentally wiped internal storage on Nexus 10 via TWRP now I can't turn on my tablet

Tags: internal-storage, twrp, samsung-nexus-10

I wanted to use TWRP to install an Android image but when I was deleting the already existing Android image files, I accidentally pressed "Internal Storage" and now when I try to operate my tablet, it does not turn on and when I put it on charge, it only gives me the battery charging icon. I also can't access bootloader.

Comment: what partitions exactly you have wiped?

Comment: i think i pressed pretty much all of them but I wasn't supposed to press internal storage @alecxs

Comment: partition list depends on fstab and can be different for each TWRP variant, therefore i don't know which partitions you wiped. i hope you didn't wipe bootloader. if it is Samsung device you should be able to flash firmware from Odin3 in download mode